# Из браузера запустить приложение камеры на Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, браузер

Возможно ли запустить из браузера приложение камеры на Android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
```

Работает на OS6+ и Android 3.0+

Comment: Спасибо Большое.